# Excel spreadsheets not opening in a scheduled task

Tags: excel, scheduled-tasks

I have an app that I wrote to scrape data from Excel spreadsheets and write the data to database tables.  This app runs fine when I run it manually.  I have set up a task through Task Scheduler to run this task but when I run it through Task Scheduler I get the message that it cannot access the spreadsheets in a log table that I created.  Is there a setting in Task Scheduler that I am missing?  We have also tried running this app through a SQL job and get the same results.

Thanks for any assistance even if it just to say that it is not possible.

I expect to see the data from the sheets in the tables which it does when I run it manually.  I am using mapped drives, but I have also tried to copy the mapped drives to my C: drive and it still gives the same error.  I am running this on a virtual machine because we want to run it after business hours.

Comment: The scheduled task runs fine on my local machine but not on the virtual machine like we need it to.

Comment: I tried a DOS batch job and got the same result.  It runs fine as a scheduled task on my local machine but fails on the virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted and rebuilt the task and it is working properly now.